# A few deployments, but max one reboot, would it work?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, reboot

**Hi!**

Could someone answer a question, please?
I have a scenario:

1. DirectSetup (DX)
2. VC 2015 Runtime
3. My product via Windows Installer (WIX)

Theoretically each element could need a reboot.
Is it possible to defer the reboot after point 3.?
For example VC 2015 Redistributable may return result that it need the restart,
but I want only one reboot. I do know know if point 3. will fail after point 2.

*Thank you very much*

Comment: I have asked the question on MS forums.
Installing DirectSetup after application (a changed order) may reduce required reboots. Maybe installing; 3. 2. 1. not 1. 2. 3. is safe, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI gives you the ability to pass the property REBOOT on the command-line - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101(v=vs.85).aspx

You could pass REBOOT=ReallySuppress to your first two installers, and then let the third reboot if necessary.

Comment: I highly appreciate the answer,
but i can not vote it.